# Native DESFire APDU Framing not worked

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I'm using Galaxy A5, Android 5.0.2, SDK 21 with Android Studio 1.1.0

Android as PCD, and Mifare DESFire as PICC. Native DESFire APDU Framing didn't work, but ISO 7816-4 worked.

Example:

MIFARE DESFire SelectApplication with AID equal to `000000h` (PICC level)

Command: `90 5a 00 00 03 00 00 00 00`.
Expected response: `91 00`.
Currently the response is `68 00`.

Document reference: [AN11004.pdf (page 33)](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11004.pdf)

```
void SelectApp() {
    _isoDep.connect();
    byte[] reqSelectApp = new byte[]{(byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x5A, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
    byte[] resSelectApp = _isoDep.transceive(reqSelectApp);
    _responseTextView.append(String.format("reqSelectApp: %s length:%d\n", BytesToHexStr(reqSelectApp), reqSelectApp.length));
    _responseTextView.append(String.format("resSelectApp: %s length:%d\n", BytesToHexStr(resSelectApp), resSelectApp.length));
}

String BytesToHexStr(byte[] items) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte item : items) {
        builder.append(String.format("%02X", item));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

#### TagInfo scan (version 4.11.59 [β4011059])

INFO

- IC manufacturer: NXP Semiconductors
- IC type: Unknown IC

NDEF

- No NFC data set storage:

EXTRA

TECH

- Technologies supported:
- ISO/IEC 14443-4 (Type A) compatible
- ISO/IEC 14443-3 (Type A) compatible
- ISO/IEC 14443-2 (Type A) compatible
- Android technology information:
  Tag description:
- TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA]
- - android.nfc.tech.IsoDep
- Maximum transceive length: 261 bytes
- Default maximum transceive time-out: 309 ms
- Extended length APDUs not supported
- - android.nfc.tech.NfcA
- Maximum transceive length: 253 bytes
- Default maximum transceive time-out: 618 ms

**No MIFARE Classic support present in Android**

Detailed protocol information:

- ID: 04:62:26:82:8A:29:80
- ATQA: 0x4403
- SAK: 0x20
- ATS: 0x1078B3C402654B5450304432654B545000
- Max. accepted frame size: 256 bytes (FSCI: 8)
- Supported receive rates: 106, 212, 424 kbit/s (DR: 1, 2, 4)
- Supported send rates: 106, 212, 424 kbit/s (DS: 1, 2, 4)
- Different send and receive rates not supported
- SFGT: 4.833 ms  (SFGI: 4)
- FWT: 1.237 s  (FWI: 12)
- NAD not supported
- CID supported
- Historical bytes: 0x654B5450304432654B5450 |eKTP0D2eKTP|

Comment: Are you sure that this is a DESFire card? Have you verified this with some other tag reader app?

Comment: So NXP TagInfo tells you that the card is **not** a DESFire card, right? Why would you expect the card to be accessible as DESFire then?

Comment: Additional readings using TagInfo(NXP), I show above. I tried using another program NFCTagInfo(NFC Research Lab Hagenberg-Michael Roland), I get information that card is DESFire.

Comment: Is possible if  my android doesn't support native protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the ATQA/SAK looks as if the card was DESFire (that's why my NFC TagInfo app detects it as such, but should give you either a read error or does indicate availability of a DESFire master application), the remaining parameters (particularly the historical bytes) clearly indicate that this is something other than a DESFire card.

Hence, don't expect the card to respond to DESFire commands (native or wrapped native). This also matches the behavior of the card as it responds with `68 00` (which indicates that the coding of the CLA byte (`0x90` in your case) is not supported).

Comment: It is the resident card, maybe data encrypted. I was confused, I tried to read the card with TagWriter (nxp), Sample App-Mifare SDK (nxp) data is also not out.The tool is very useful for me. Thank you for answers. Nice to meet you :).