# NFC Apdu Response 67 00 (wrong length) on Android using isodep

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

i tried to send extended APDU command into Desfire card on Android.

i was select the application on the card and success.
but when i tried to authentication process and send this command, i got response 67 00 (wrong length)

i send data :

**00820000288C9D8E3837E8E47514E9010801C1615E65E677A21DC40E07B32DF6DE24EED3D6CD950BA8CB5E738528**

where:

```
CLA : 0x00

INS : 0x82

P1  : 0x00

P2  : 0x00

Lc  : 0x28 //(40 bytes)
```

data  :

**0x8C, 0x9D, 0x8E, 0x38, 0x37, 0xE8, 0xE4, 0x75, 0x14, 0xE9, 0x01, 0x08, 0x01, 0xC1
, 0x61, 0x5E, 0x65, 0xE6, 0x77, 0xA2, 0x1D, 0xC4, 0x0E, 0x07, 0xB3, 0x2D, 0xF6, 0xDE
, 0x24, 0xEE, 0xD3, 0xD6, 0xCD, 0x95, 0x0B, 0xA8, 0xCB, 0x5E, 0x73, 0x85**

```
**Le  : 0x28 (expected return length)**
```

i think there is nothing wrong with the command structure, but why the response is 67 00

i am using isodep library.

please some one help me..

Comment: You specify CLA=80, but your data starts with 00 ?

Comment: sorry, its typo. CLA= 0x00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External authentication in DESFire card with ISO 7816-4 APDUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425494/external-authentication-in-desfire-card-with-iso-7816-4-apdus)

Comment: if i deleted the last byte (Le), the response is 63 00

Comment: So the command is executed now. I admit that a status denoting *warning processing, no information given*(see 7816-4)  is not overly helpful.

Comment: but when i used a contactless reader and execute on pc the apdu command (with Le 0x28) it's can executed successfully with 90 00 response apdu

Comment: The exact same command? Isn't it a challenge response protocol where you have to retrieve the challenge first? Usually it is randomized, otherwise you could replay commands (not just you, an attacker).

Comment: no, the data changed depend on challenge response apdu (only the data changed)

Comment: @iwan_odank hey, did you manage to find where was the problem?